# Trace inequality

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, trace

If $$\sum \Vert Ae_n \Vert \leq \sum \Vert B e_n \Vert$$

How we can conclude that

$$\operatorname{Tr}|A| \leq \operatorname{Tr}|B|$$
where $|A|=(A^{\ast} A)^{1/2}$ and $e_n$ are orthonormal basis

Comment: Is the first inequality valid for all vectors $e_n$ of the orthonormal basis? So for instance if $A$ is a 3x3 matrix, one could use $e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $e_3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Karlo yes it is valid for all orthonormal basis

Comment: Is the vector norm in the first inequality specified, or is it valid for any norm?

Comment: @Karlo any norm induced by inner product space

Comment: I suppose $A$ and $B$ are positive definite?

Comment: No, only |A| and |B|

Comment: What do you mean by taking the square root of $A^*A$?

Comment: This means |A|^2= A*A

Comment: Let me try to phrase it another way. Most matrices admit multiple square roots (some admit infinitely many). When a matrix $M$ is positive (semi)definite, however, it admits a single positive (semi)definite square root; this is $M$'s *principal square root*, and is generally what is understood when one writes $M^{1/2}$. If we're not in this case, how should we know which of the square roots of $A^*A$ to take? Notice that the trace may depend on the choice of square root.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri thank for clarifying.. but i think that A* A is psd

Comment: Even if A is not psd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reading your question I presume $A^*$ indicates a conjugate transpose and by $||\vec v||$ you mean the norm $\sqrt{\vec v\cdot\vec v}$ where $\vec v\cdot\vec v\equiv\vec v^*\vec v$. I'll use the same convention.

Let $\vec a_n$ be the columns of $A$. Then the left side of your first inequality can be written as:

$$\sum ||A\hat e_n||=\sum||\vec a_n||=\sum\sqrt{\vec a_n\cdot\vec a_n}$$

It follows from the properties of matrix multiplication that the entries of $A^*A$ are dot products of its columns. Specifically:

$$(A^*A)_{ij}=\vec a_i\cdot\vec a_j$$

If we take the trace, we sum over indices

$$\text{Tr}(A^*A)=(A^*A)_{1,1}+(A^*A)_{2,2}+...=\sum(A^*A)_{nn}=\sum\vec a_n\cdot\vec a_n$$

Now if we let $\sqrt{\ }$ denote an elementwise square root, we can take the trace of $\sqrt{A^*A}$ by taking the square root of the elements in the sum.

$$\text{Tr}\sqrt{A^*A}=\sum\sqrt{\vec a_n\cdot\vec a_n}$$

From this, we see that the quantities on the left sides of both inequalities are identical. Clearly, the same is true for the right sides. Therefore your inequalities describe exactly the same statement, constructed in slightly different ways.

If, instead, we interpret $\sqrt{}$ as a matrix square root (that is, $\sqrt A$ is a unique matrix s.t. $\sqrt A\sqrt A=A$, then the the inequalities are not equivalent. To see why notice that the statement can be rephrased as follows.

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive semidefinite Hermitian matrices and $\sqrt A$, $\sqrt B$ be their matrix square roots.

$$\sum\sqrt{A_{ii}}\le\sum\sqrt{B_{ii}}\implies\text{Tr}\sqrt A\le\text{Tr}\sqrt{B}$$

A counterexample to this would be

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1        & \frac 12 \\
\frac 12 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}
1        & \frac 16 \\
\frac 16 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you ,But the root of the matrix is not equal to the root of its elements , how we can handle this?or is it true that at least that when we take the root for $A^*A$ that the matrix obtained has diagonal entries equal to the root diagonal entries  for $A^*A$ .